# mov rax,[res] does not work in macho64

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, mach-o, mov

My code:

```
section .data
   res db 0

section .text
   global _main
   extern _printf
   extern _scanf

_main
   ..blablabla.....
   mov rax,[res]
   ..blablbabla....
ret
```

And error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses on `mov rax,[res]`.

So, in macho64, I can't link `res`, in `[res]`?

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know macho64 format, but there are alternatives to `mov rax,[res]`:

```
mov rax,res
mov rax,[rax]
```

Or using RIP-relative addressing:

```
mov rax,[rel res]
```

Comment: Thx, nrz. I repeat it tomorrow! :)

Comment: `rel` should be your first suggestion, or a `default rel` directive. 
 Also, `mov rax, res` will assemble to `mov r64, imm64`, with a 64-bit absolute address.  `lea rdi, [rel res]` is a more efficient (and smaller, and position-independent) way to get the pointer in a register.  Or for AL/AX/EAX/RAX specifically, you *can* use a 64-bit absolute address if you really want: `mov rax, [qword res]` to get something like `48 a1 8a 00 40 00 00 00 00 00   movabs rax,ds:0x40008a`.  But RIP-relative is more efficient.